# Reuse Process in golang to persist environment variables

Tags: go, environment-variables

I'm currently struggling with reusing process in golang.

Some more context:
The CLI I'm building is going to be used within development, the CLI will be used so setup the development environment en make deployment / building and testing simple by supporting this out of the box. To make the CLI flexible I would like to enable users to integrate custom defined scripts. One script for example overrides the docker environment variables so that the CLI deploy script deploys to the correct environment. Those environment are exposed using the following command: `minikube docker-env` this script prints out the `export` statements to the `stdout`. Normally you would run `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to apply those environment variables to your current shell. But I would like my CLI to be able to share those variables across scripts.

Now let's say I've two commands defined. `A` and `B`. Both commands are simple bash script. But could are run inside mode or python for example.

Script `A`:

```
export FOO="bar"
```

Script `B`:

```
echo $FOO
```

Both those script are executed like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command(bash, [PATH_TO_SCRIPT])
stdout, err := cmd.Output()
```

What I would like to achieve is that there is one process in which those scripts are executed but I struggle to find a way how.

The reason I want to achieve this via own defined scripts is that the users of the CLI easily can add script and make use of those environment variables later on.

Comment: You can't do that from Go, or any language. A process can fork another process by executing a binary; the process ends when the binary exits.

Comment: @Adrian Do you have any other solution in mind that might work?

Comment: Hard to say without any details on context... you could write a third wrapper script that runs the other two, or you could specify the environment variables outside the scripts in a myriad of ways.

Comment: I could provide some more context:

The CLI I'm building is going to be used within development, the CLI will be used so setup the development environment en make deployment / building and testing simple by supporting this out of the box.

To make the CLI flexible I would like to enable users to integrate custom defined scripts.

One script for example overrides the docker environment variables so that the CLI deploy script deploys to the correct environment.

I thought it would be possible by using the same process for both scripts.

Would it be possible to create a shell instance?

Comment: Why would you use a script to override environment variables? Wouldn't it be better to just use them normally, either set in the user's profile or per-command using `env`? And why does this involve so much executing bash from Go? I would think it would be preferable to use all bash or all Go rather than mixing and mangling the two.

Comment: @Adrian The CLI is written in Go so the users of this CLI won't notice anything of it. That's the reason why I'm looking for something that can run different scripts. I already mentioned the reason why I would like to set environment variables via those script, cause those script for example can define to what docker environment to build.
The people that are going to use this CLI expect it to work flexible but also simplicity in how to use it. It should be easy and flexible to integrate with different tooling. For example Minikube. The CLI is meant for developing microservice architectures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer to your question other than: impossible. That is because your question involves a fundamental misunderstanding how UNIX environment variables work and how the Go language `exec.Command()` function works. There is no way for a process to modify the environment variables of its parent; or any other program. The Go lang `exec.Command()` call starts a new process which cannot affect the environment variables of the process performing that action. You need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and explaining how the UNIX environment variables work. Do you have any suggestions what could work?

Comment: @toonvanstrijp Typically you would have the child script write statements like `export A=x` to stdout. Then the parent script executes it using `eval $(child_script)`. A very dangerous practice. You could do the same thing by having your program written in Go parse the output, recognize such assignments, and convert them into `os.Setenv()` Go function calls. Having said that I don't understand why you've chosen this architecture, and therefore, cannot provide a good answer.

Comment: I added some more context to my question above. If you think my architecture decision is incorrect or think there is a better approach please let me know.

Comment: The answer is worded a little oddly so I wanted to clarify - Go *can* set the environment variables for the process started with `exec.Command.Env`: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd

Comment: @AdrianYes, but that isn't what the person asking the question is trying to do. They want the process started by `exec.Command()` to modify the environment of the Go process.